# Back Button not working quickly, Take 4-5 Second Webview to back, How to get Progress SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, button, swiftui, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'm writing a Webapp in swiftUI with xcode13.1  I've a question "How can I add a progress bar that shows me the loading of page when user click on back button?

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebViewForCommunityTab : UIViewRepresentable {

let request: URLRequest
var webview: WKWebView?

init(web: WKWebView?, req: URLRequest) {
    self.webview = WKWebView()
    self.request = req
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
    return webview!
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    uiView.load(request)
}

func goBack(){
    webview?.goBack()
}

func goForward(){
    webview?.goForward()
}

func goHomeScreen(){
    webview?.load(URLRequest(url: (URL(string: DefaultUrlString.CommunityWebLink)!)))
}
}


struct WebContentView: View {

let webview = WebViewForHomeTab(web: nil, req: URLRequest(url: URL(string: DefaultUrlString)!))

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            VStack (spacing: 80) {
                webview
            }
            HStack (alignment: .center) {
                Group {
                    Spacer()
                    CustomButtonForWebView(btnImageTitle: ArrowLeftCircleImg, action: {
                        self.webview.goBack()
                    })
                    CustomButtonForWebView(btnImageTitle: ArrowRightCircleImg, action: {
                        self.webview.goForward()
                    })
                    Spacer()
                }.padding(.bottom,10)
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth, height: 40, alignment: .center)
        }.hiddenNavigationBarStyle().background(Color.white)
    }
}
}
```

Question: How to get Progress in the WKWebView when user click on back button?

Can someone please explain to me How to get Progress?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.